# Content Disposition JAVA

Tags: java

I need to build a code where I have to make the content disposition automatically.Means I need to fetch some text fields,some image fields,some sounds and all of the request I have to take with the post request,I can not use the get request. So please say me how can I buld the content disposition in java?

Comment: It's very unclear what you're try to do, to be honest. Are you writing the server? The client? What are you doing with the data, and what do you want to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Its kind of unclear. But as far as I understand it I'll try to explain. The post request must be a button,so in that button you define the action of that button. set action on click and in that method try to get all the values,i.e., for text field data use gettext() and so on.